# How to build a linux distribution based on ubuntu/debian/mint easily?

Tags: linux, linux-distributions, linux-mint

Is there a tool or tutorial to build a distro based on mint/ubuntu/debian?

Git, scripts, and tools, small compilations for branding are OK. Compiling kernel, x11, gnome, compiz, etc. is BAD unless really required.

Specifically, I'm looking for a way to have some applications installed by default, change logos/about boxes, change theme, configure what compiz options are, and add firmware drivers (connect to the Internet to download wireless adapter driver? <- headache, gotta find a lan cable now ...), and still have the liveCD install method. I'd like it to be based on linux mint, but I only want a few tools from it (update manager, software manager, flash, media codecs), so it's ok if it's ubuntu/debian with those mint tools added back in.

I saw some options, too complex, and others too simple. Not looking for a "learning experience" like LFS which gives me a horrible linux build if I don't do something exactly right. Nor any of those tools which are just package pickers and don't do enough. suse studio looked about right(maybe tad too easy), but was RPM based, not deb based. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like [Reconstructor](http://maketecheasier.com/reconstructor-creating-your-own-ubuntu-distribution/2008/07/05) or [Novo](http://maketecheasier.com/build-your-own-ubuntu-based-distro-with-novo-builder/2010/07/02).